# How to create an independent HTML block?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I want to know if there is some way to create an independent HTML block .

For more explanation : 
My problem is that I have a webpage in which I allow some users can add content (may contain HTML & CSS ) 
I allow them to add their content inside a certain  block , but sometimes their content may not be clean code , and may contain some DIVS with no end , Or even some DIV end with no starting DIV 
This sometimes distort my page completely

Is there any way to make their content displayed independently from my parent div , so that my div is first displayed well , and then the content inside it is displayed ?

I'm sorry for long message .
Thanks for any trial to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> sometimes their content may not be clean code , and may contain some
>   DIVS with no end , Or even some DIV end with no starting DIV This
>   sometimes distort my page completely

The easiest solution for you is going to be to add the submitted content to your page inside an `<iframe>`. That way, it doesn't matter if the submitted HTML is invalid.

If you have to worry about users possibly submitting malicious content (such as JavaScript), the problem becomes much harder: you need to sanitize the HTML. I can't tell you how to do this without knowing what server-side language you're using.

Comment: Hi ,I used Iframe and it worked fine for me.I tried one more thing that also worked for me to an extent.I have taken the submitted contents(in valid HTML) in a documentFragment.I have waited till full dom constructed and after that i have taken the innerHTML of documentFragment and put that in a div where i wish to render it on the page.It worked for me with out distorting the lay out of entire page.Is it a right approach to take ?

Comment: That sounds good. I think `DocumentFragment` applies the browser's error correction to the provided HTML, so it should be difficult to end up with something that will break the page. Though I'm not really familiar with `DocumentFragment`, so don't take my word for it.

Answer (score 4):

> My problem is that I have a webpage in which I allow some users can add content (may contain HTML & CSS ) I allow them to add their content inside a certain block , but sometimes their content may not be clean code , and may contain some DIVS with no end , Or even some DIV end with no starting DIV This sometimes distort my page completely

If that is the problem you are trying to solve, then having some markup to say a chunk of code was independent wouldn't help: They might include the "End of independent section" code in the HTML.

If you want to put the code in a page, you need to parse it, sanitise it (using a whitelist) to remove anything potentially harmful and then generate clean markup from the DOM.

Comment: Either clean it, or shove it all into an iframe..? Perhaps that's not an option in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you could use Static iframes.
check this out http://www.samisite.com/test-csb2nf/id43.htm

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to restrict the tags they can submit, and validate/sanitize those that they do, similar to the way we can use markup on here.

Having unchecked HTML injected into your page is asking for trouble.

Failing that, good old `iframe` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i belive there is something you can do, but it can require some time. You can use a parser to go through the users html, and get the tags and their content, and recreate the html making it clean.

But, as there are a lot of tags that can be used, or even invented tags, than you can limit the tags that the user are able to use in their html. You put a legend with the acceptable tags.

There are some pretty good html parsers for php, but they may break for some very bad html code, so this is why i suggest you just recreate it based on the parsing with a limited subset of acceptable tags.

I know it's a difficult/time consuming solution, but this is what i have in mind